# Ajuda para pegar input ajax com laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Preciso pegar o input city do form abaixo, uso em laravel $input['city'] mas não pega. Já o uf $input['uf'] pega, abaixo o codigo.

```
<select name="uf" id="uf" class="form-control">
<option value="">-- Escolha o Estado --</option>
```

```
<select name="city" id="city" class="form-control" data-bind="value: params.city" style="display:none;"></select>
```

```js
<script> var selectCidades</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 //json � uma variavel 'global'
 var json;
 
 
 //Vamos fazer um Ajax s� de zoas
 ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();  
 //Pega uma um array de estados com array de cidades Cortesia do gitzeiro: @letanure
 ajax.open('GET', 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/letanure/3012978/raw/36fc21d9e2fc45c078e0e0e07cce3c81965db8f9/estados-cidades.json', true);
 ajax.send();
 
 ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
  
   //Parsea o text para JSON
   json = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
  
   //Percorre todos os estados
   for(i in json.estados){
    var estado = json.estados[i];
    
    //Cria a a cidade na tag 'Option'
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = estado.nome;
    option.value = estado.sigla;
    
    //Insere no Select(uf) as options criadas
    var selectUf = document.getElementById("uf");
    selectUf.appendChild(option);
   }
  }
 }
 
 //Monitra o evento Change, e assim que ocorrer altera��o, exibe as cidades do mesmo (aproveitando a mesma requisi��o (var json))
 document.getElementById('uf').addEventListener('change', function() { 
  //Pega o Estado que o cara selecionou... Ex: 'SP'
  var ufSelecionado = this.value;
  
  //Deixa o Select de Cidades Facil para manipular
  var selectCidades = document.getElementById("city");
  
  //Remove todas as cidades (caso esteja trocando)
  while (selectCidades.firstChild) {
   selectCidades.removeChild(selectCidades.firstChild);
  }
  
  //Percorre todo o Loop de estados
  for(i in json.estados){
   var estado = json.estados[i];   
   //Caso a sigla seja a mesma selecionada
   if(estado.sigla == ufSelecionado){
   
    for(x in estado.cidades){
     var cidade = estado.cidades[x];
     
     //Cria a a cidade na tag 'Option'
     var option = document.createElement("option");
     option.text = cidade;
     option.value = x;
     
     //Insere no Select a tag criada   
     selectCidades.appendChild(option);
     
     //Retira a condi��o de 'Esconder'
     selectCidades.style.display = null;
    }
    
    //Break loop (Improve performace?)
    return false;
   }
  }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Qual parte do código não está funcionando?

Comment: tudo funciona, escolho o e mostra as cidades, que não estou conseguindo fazer é pegar o nome da cidade. $input['city'] somente pega o id.

Comment: Mas isso nao tem no codigo da pergunta.

Comment: O $input['city'] está pegando o value?